# How to get available Glyph ranges in a font using FreeType lib API

Tags: freetype, freetype2

I need to get ranges of the available glyphs in a given font file/face.

The brute force of iterating `cp in 0..65535`, calling `FT_Get_Char_Index(cp)`, and checking for 0 result seems wrong, both because Unicode code point could be more than u16, and because it seems wasteful.

Is there any "iteration" API?

Comment: [FT_Get_First_Char](https://freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-character_mapping.html#ft_get_first_char) and [FT_Get_Next_Char](https://freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-character_mapping.html#ft_get_next_char)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions [FT_Get_First_Char](https://freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-character_mapping.html#ft_get_first_char) and [FT_Get_Next_Char](https://freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-character_mapping.html#ft_get_next_char) can be used to parse all character codes available in a given charmap.

There is an example at `FT_Get_First_Char`.